# Why does Azure DevOps notifications email delays

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have setup team serviceto notify me about any tasks assigned to me or whenever I am tagged in a task.

The first problem is, in my phone(gmail,outlook app) I have setup synchronization to be done every 15minutes but this is not being done...I am obliged everytime to synchronize manually to see my emails, same thing is happening with my teammate.

Second problem is whenever I get tagged or a task assigned to me... the email in the normal outlook webapp or windows 10 app is reaching a little bit late.

Is that how Azure Devops notification work by default ?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your email client.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel Mann, the problem is not referred to the `Azure DevOps` directly.

Anyway, try to switch your phone to use the `push model` of getting emails.

Second, open the email in the desktop client, there has to be a possibility to see the headers of the message, and copy that to 
[G Suite Toolbox Messageheader](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/analyzeheader). It shows how much time it takes to go through the internet to your particular mailbox. It usually takes seconds. If the time is acceptable, then the main cause could be in the configuration of your email client.

Answer (score 0):

An email is generated when an event occurs within Azure DevOps Services which matches a notification subscription. See the [notifications overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=vsts) for more information about notification subscriptions.

If you're not receiving an expected notification email, it could be for the following reason:

- Your organization is creating a very large volume notifications

Please perform the following step to determine if it resolves the issue.

***Step*** : Check the notification statistics for unexpectedly high volume
Poorly defined subscription filters or duplicate subscriptions might cause an unexpected high volume of notifications, causing a delay in the processing or delivery of emails. Learn [how to view and analyze notification statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-view-organization-notification-statistics?view=vsts).

If you're not able to resolve the issue with the steps above, consider contacting [customer support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/troubleshoot-contact-support?view=vsts).